# Create a custom list as primary key in mockaroo but can't set it as foreign to another dataset

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, extract

I am using Mockaroo to extract data to be inserted in my PostgreSQL database. The problem I am facing is that I can't change the type field to a value other than "row number". I want my primary key not to follow the standard (1,2,3,4....etc). I want to place my default values.

[image]

The picture above shows that I am setting the store_id as digit sequence that generates random numbers (1001, 1020, etc.)

Now, I am going to my "USER" dataset as shown below and placing the store_id as dataset column, in order to set it as Foreign Key.

[image]

As soon as, I am updating my "USER" dataset, I am receiving the following error.

[image]

Any ideas on how to bypass this?

I've tried everything and searched online a lot, but didn't find anything specific.